# How to access an attribute of an item in an ICollection using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

This is in ASP.NET MVC 4,

I have a Portfolios Table and one of the properties of the Portfolio class is an ICollection of Stocks. Stocks have a string property: Symbol. If I have the portfolio object I am trying to check the symbol of a specific stock to see if it matches what I am looking for.

```
private PortfolioDb _db = new PortfolioDb();

public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix="id")]int portfolioId, 
    string searchTerm = null)
{
      var portfolio = _db.Portoflios
                      .Where(p=> searchTerm == null   || 
                               (p.Id == portfolioId && p.Stocks.Symbol == searchTerm)
```

So `p.Stocks` is my `ICollection` of Stocks and I want to check the symbol of all those stocks to see if they match the searchTerm. However, I cannot do `p.Stocks.Symbol` and I am wondering how I would access each symbol of each item in the Stocks collection.

Thanks

Comment: you might need to combine queries using [groupby](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7325278/1698987)

Comment: What do you want back? The stock objects? All portfolios with those stocks?

Comment: I want to find the portfolio that has the matching portfolioId and has a Stock object in its list of Stocks that has a Symbol that matches the searchTerm. So 1 == 1 AND "MSFT" == "MSFT"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.Any` to find the portfolio that has any stock matching the searchterm::

`&& p.Stocks.Any(s => s.Symbol == searchTerm)`

Comment: This worked for my problem. Was messing with .Select instead of .Any. Thank you.